# ERROR: npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@type%2fjsonwebwebtoken - Not found

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jwt

I am trying to add this package in terminal in visual studio but there is a error and i am clueless please help. I coding for first time.

```
npm install @type/jsonwebwebtoken graphql-request next-auth
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@type%2fjsonwebwebtoken - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@type/jsonwebwebtoken@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

please help to resolve this issue.[ss-of-the-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqcWr.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to install the type definitions for this package, which is `npm i -D @types/jsonwebtoken`